# mySQL Inner Join with two the same foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, database, inner-join

I have a table

```
Question
->id
->question_name
->columnheader
```

and

```
Mutual
-id
->question_id_1
->question_id_2
```

And basically I need to make a list of records from `Mutual` table but I can't just show the `question_id_1` and `question_id_2` so I need to make an inner join. Problem is I have `question_id_1` and `question_id_2` as my both foreign key.

If I my structure is like

```
Mutual
->id
->question_id
```

Then I can simply

```
Select b.id, a.question_name FROM question a INNER JOIN mutual b ON a.id = b.question_id
```

How to do it like in my current database structure? I want to show both `question_id_1` and `the`question_name` from question table

Comment: Did you mean "I want to show both `question_id_1` and the `question_id_2`" right?

Comment: Can you show the expected END RESULT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT m.id, q1.`question_name`, q2.`question_name` 
FROM `mutual` m 
INNER JOIN `Question` q1 ON q1.`id` = m.`question_id_1` 
INNER JOIN `Question` q2 ON q2.`id` = m.`question_id_2`
```

Comment: I much prefer aliases of `q1` and `q2` to `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I really would like to see the expected end result, but you can UNION items like this:

```
SELECT q.id, question_name FROM mutual m 
INNER JOIN question q 
ON q.id = m.question_id_1 

UNION

SELECT q.id, question_name FROM mutual m 
INNER JOIN question q 
ON q.id = m.question_id_2
```